# How do I debug server and client simultaneously in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have a node.js app that runs a server and sends index.html. The index.html interacts with the server.

I want to debug the complete app, but when I debug the app, WebStorm only debugs the server.

Is this even possible in WebStorm? If not, are there other tools that can do this?

Comment: Should be possible, yes. One Run/Debug Configuration to start Node.js debug (your server app). And separate one for standard JavaScript debug for your client code. No instructions from me though (not a JS/Node.js person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) run configuration, [Browser/Live Edit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html#browser-live-edit-tab) tab, specify the URL of your server, tick both **After launch** and **with JavaScript debugger** checkboxes - client-side debugger will be launched once you start your node server with this configuration, so that you will be able to debug both simultaneously, using a single run configuration.

See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#debugging_js_on_external_web_server for some hints on debugging client-side code run in browser