# Debugging Node.js server and React client simultaneously in WebStorm 2019.2: breakpoints don't 'break'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've tried following the directions here -- [How do I debug server and client simultaneously in WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836011/how-do-i-debug-server-and-client-simultaneously-in-webstorm) -- but what happens is my Node app starts, a Chrome window opens with my client -- all good so far.  I had set a couple of breakpoints that should be hit as the app boots up but there is no 'break' -- the app starts and works fine, but that's it.  Is there some step I'm missing?  Both debugging setups seem to be running (see pic)

[image]

EDIT:

Here's what I put in my configuration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: should be possible when using instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836011/how-do-i-debug-server-and-client-simultaneously-in-webstorm. In your **NLPJS-App client/server Javascript** run configuration (the [Javascript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) one), try enabling **Ensure breakpoints are detected when loading scripts** and re-run the debugger - does it make any difference?

Comment: @lena -- There's only the one run configuration -- NLPJS-App client/server -- which is a Node.js configuration, where I went to the tab 'browser / live edit' and clicked the boxes 'after launch' and 'with Javascript debugger'.  I don't see where to enable 'ensure breakpoints are detected...'.  Is there only one config?  From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/node-debug-server-client.html, it says " Node.js run configuration to start together with a JavaScript Debug configuration."  Was there some step I missed?  What does "...to start together with a JavaScript Debug configuration" mean?

Comment: @lena ...tried it with new config.  Sometimes it stops in server code, sometimes not.  Sometimes takes one minute before the first breakpoint in server code is hit (perhaps this is a function of the app?).  Doesn't stop in client code.

Comment: I edited to add pics of my configuration

Comment: the configuration is normally created automatically (it's shown in the active configurations popup in your first screenshot - strange that it's not available in *Run/Debug configurations*).

Comment: Try creating the configuration manually (and clear the *After launch* in *Browser/Live Edit* tab) - does it work if you start the server, then choose the manually created JavaScript Debug configuration and hit *Debug*?

Comment: I think I see what the problem is -- I'm used to running Node with React apps that are running under 'create react app' or similar, that is to say, they're being dynamically served. This app is starting up a backend server that also is serving already built react files. I've been told that debugging the build files will work with Chrome's debugger as long as a source map has been provided. Would it also work with WebStorm if there are source maps available as part of the build process?

Comment: sure, debugging should work if the sourcemaps are there